# Javascript won't apply css-style on dynamic table

Tags: javascript, css

After some research on the internet I discovered that you can add your CSS-class to a new created row with .classname:

```
<tr id="producttablerow" 
    onClick='
        var table = document.getElementById("cardtable");
        var row = table.insertRow(-1);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.className ="cardlefttd";
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell2.className ="cardcentretd";
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        cell3.className ="cardrighttd";

        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";              
        cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
'>
```

But when I run this on my website, I can see there is no style applied, but there's style applied on the static part of the website, so my css is working fine, I guess the problem is in the javascript part above, and I doubt if this sentence is right:

```
        cell3.className ="cardrighttd";
```

The onClick is working fine, I've tried it with an alert.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't think echo is js.

Comment: @Alek I know that, the javascript code is inside a PHP code and the javascript and html is echo'd by PHP. That's also why I needed to use backslashes in my code.

Comment: Rule number one, provide minimal code to reproduce the problem. If your problem is with your JS, we do not need to see your PHP around it. Please our eyes by removing it. Second, if it does not work, try it in a "standalone" version, a simble HTML page with your JS. Third, do not write all your JS in `onClick`, make it a function, that will make everything easier to read :)

Comment: I'll delete the PHP, and I know the onClick function is working (should have mentioned that), and the rows are being added but the css style isn't applied.

Comment: That's better! The syntax looks ok to me, I just noticed there is an L missing in `cel2.className`...

Comment: Must have made the mistake with reformatting, at my site there are 2 l's and it's still not working :/

Comment: I just added an L and your code works.. [**Try it**](http://jsfiddle.net/2L5gj/).

Comment: It seems to work for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9VBu3/)

Comment: IMHO that's the worst way to write code. Write a separate function an attach it to click event..

Comment: Look in your javascript console (**F12**), are there any errors?

Comment: Set up a fiddle and include the CSS.  The js looks fine.  It may be a CSS issue.

Comment: The problem isn't the javascript, it's the CSS. I saw you created your class with a dot '.', i did it with '#' and the .className isn;t working with css-classes defined by '#'.

Comment: That's because # does not create a css Class, but a CSS-ID. You can use those in JS with `obj.id` instead of `obj.className`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments above, to just explain why the dot fixed it.

- In css, a # is used to reference an id.
- A class is referenced by a dot

The javascript is adding classes and not ids.

If used on more than one element on a page, you should use a class and not an id.  id's should be used to refer to a single item only if you want your code to validate.